# Disable form authentication for WCF call

Tags: asp.net, wcf, forms-authentication

I am using `ASP.NET4.5 with C#`. In my web-application, there is a `form authentication` implemented that uses `cookie` to store authentication information.

In `web.config` it is specified as :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Now, I have a `WCF RESTfull` service for which I am using `custom basic authentication`. For each service call I need to set an authentication header and if it is not valid then I have to return response with `401` code.

The code is as below :

```
public class BasicAuthenticationInterceptor : RequestInterceptor
{
    MembershipProvider provider;
    string realm;

    public BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(MembershipProvider provider, string realm)
        : base(false)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
        this.realm = realm;
    }

    protected string Realm
    {
        get { return realm; }
    }

    protected MembershipProvider Provider
    {
        get { return provider; }
    }

    public override void ProcessRequest(ref RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty request = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)requestContext.RequestMessage.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
        string[] credentials = ExtractCredentials(requestContext.RequestMessage);

        if (credentials.Length > 0 && AuthenticateUser(credentials[0], credentials[1]))
        {
            InitializeSecurityContext(requestContext.RequestMessage, credentials[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Message reply = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, "Invalid Action", "Access Denied");
                HttpResponseMessageProperty responseProperty = new HttpResponseMessageProperty() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized };

                responseProperty.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate",
                String.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", Realm));
                responseProperty.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "text/html";
                reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = responseProperty;
                requestContext.Reply(reply);
                requestContext = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex.InnerException;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, to prevent `form authetication` for `WCF` call, I have added following tag in `web.config` :

```
<location path="MyService.svc">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Note that, the WCF placed in "`Service`" directory of my project, I have tried using `path="~/service/MyService.svc"`, `path="service/MyService.svc"`, `path="service"` in location tab, but it is returning `200`, NOT `401` code.

Now, I have tested the service call using `Fire-fox RESTClient add-on` and found that for `invalid request` it is still returning `200 code` and in `row-body` I am getting `HTML` of my `login.aspx` page. That means it is still redirecting to `login.aspx`.

If I change the `authetication mode` in `web.config` to "`None`" then service call works fine with returning `401` code for `invalid request`. But I can not set authentication mode to "None".

Please let me know how to prevent the form authentication for WCF call.

Comment: Have you verified the Path of SVC file.

Comment: Ya. It is in service directory of my application. I have tested it with path="~/service/MyService.svc", path="service/MyService.svc" and path="service", but did not get 401.

Comment: Are these settings present in application root web.config?

Comment: Yes. I don't have any other web.config in my project.

Comment: Any experts available..?

Comment: Try setting bounty, to get attention of folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it my self :

I have added following code in `Application_AuthenticateRequest()` event of `Global.asax` and it is working fine now :

```
HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;

if (context.Request.Url.ToString().Contains(".svc"))
{
    context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
}
```